# How to parse URL safe query parameters into readable strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found one library, [jQuery URL Parser](http://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser), which seems to be full-featured as far as parsing out the various segments of a URL. I'm trying to go one step further though, and parse the *values* of the query parameters.

For example, given the URL `"http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=rm+-rf+%2F"` I'd like to get `"rm -rf /"` for the `q` parameter. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

As a side note, I'm not operating on the URL of the current page so any `location` magic doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though the library you referenced can indeed retrieve query string values as given under the section called `Query string parameters`:

> The .param() method is used to return
>   the values of querystring parameters.
>
> Pass in a string to access that
>   parameter's value:
>
> `$.url('http://allmarkedup.com?sky=blue&grass=green').param('sky');
>   // returns 'blue' If no argument is
>   passed in it will return an object
>   literal containing a key:value map of
>   all the querystring parameters.`
>
> `$.url('http://allmarkedup.com?sky=blue&grass=green').param();
>   // returns { 'sky':'blue',
>   'grass':'green' } Note that the
>   .param() method will work on both
>   ampersand-split and semicolon-split
>   querystrings.`

Comment: This probably should be used together with `decodeURIComponent` to achieve what the OP wants..

Comment: The combination of mellamokb's answer, Shadow Wizard's comment and replacing `+`s with spaces worked worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use your own small lightweight code to do just that :

```
    function getParam(url, param) {
        if (!url.indexOf('?')) {
            return 'undefined';
        }
        url = url.split('?')[1];
        var arr = url.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var key = arr[i].split('=')[0], val = arr[i].split('=')[1];
            if (key === param) {
                return val;
            }
        }
        return 'undefined';
    }
```